# options_for_select is unclickable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to use a select in a partial, but it is not showing nor is clickable

```
<div class="trade-select-wrap">
    <div>
      <div class="custom-select">
          <%= f.select :related_by, options_for_select([['option1', 'option2', 'option3']]), {} %>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: And if you change [options_for_select](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_for_select) to `options_for_select(['option1', 'option2', 'option3'])`? It should be flat collection

Comment: Can you show how has been implemented `render partial`?

Answer (score 3):

I've a couple of suggestions:

a) make sure you're passing the correct form object `f` to the partial, something like (assuming this partial is named `_form.html.erb`):

```
<%= render 'form', f: f %>
```

b) `options_for_select(['option1', 'option2', 'option3'])`, note the difference: `[]` vs `[[]]`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the following,

```
f.select("model-name", "column-name", ["Option1", "Option2","Option3"], {:selected => f.object.colomn-name, :prompt => 'Select Option *'})
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually never mind, this is a bit embarrassing but it was a CSS issue sorry